# Terminal GDM session

Tags: command-line, login, gdm

How would I create a session file so that when I login using GDM it just launches a terminal session (No windowing, just a plain terminal like in Ubuntu Server)?

Comment: And why GDM and not TTY1?

Comment: Because   I am creating  a distro that is for small business I would have a TUI login using dialog but I haven't been able to find the right answer for that. So Im opting for a login manager to which it goes to tty1 then starts a custom TUI management console.

Comment: You can switch to TTY1 by calling `chvt 1`, but it doesn't login automatically.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager#Console